# How to get the Dataset if there are null values in some of the fields

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

```
DataSet ds = ast.GetUserLoginInfo(Param);

foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            _userstate.ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"]);
            _userstate.Name = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"]).Trim();
            _userstate.Email = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"]).Trim();
            _userstate.Username = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"]).Trim();              
            _userstate.GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["GroupId"]);
            _userstate.BranchId = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BranchId"]);
            _userstate.BranchId = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DeptId"]);
            _userstate.RoleId = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RoleId"]);
            _userstate.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsActive"]);

            _siteuser.UserStat = _userstate;
        }
```

For some users  BranchId is null as they are the head and all the branches come under them. Therefore database returns nonthing in dataset when a user logs in.

Comment: So? What's the question?

Comment: You're assigning `DeptId` to `BranchId` am pretty sure you didn't intended it.

Comment: Heading makes no sense. What do you meant by *How to get the Dataset if there are null values in some of the fields* ? Get the dataset? You already have dataset!

Comment: Error? What is the error? Post it.

Comment: The reference variable ds is pointing to nothing .

Comment: The code above is written in the try block. Exception is being catched.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey , Could you mind posting the exception/ error ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for all the fields,

```
 _userstate.ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"] == null ? 0 : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"]);
 _userstate.Name = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"] == null ? "" ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"] ).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since branchId is nullable, ConvertToInt32 throw an exception. try this instead.

```
int.TryParse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BranchId",  _userstate.BranchId)
```

Comment: It is throwing compile time error "No overLoad for TryParse method takes one argument"

Comment: @Smokingmonkey : you are right, i correct it, its second argument set the result. it should work. try it